# Cannot insert Null

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, null, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using code-first migrations and using apis post method. but it is giving me the error below:

> "InnerException": { "Message": "An error has occurred.",
>   "ExceptionMessage": "Cannot insert the value NULL into column
>   'AttendeeId', table
>   'aspnet-WebApplication-20171216054501.dbo.Attendances'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.",
>   "Exception Type": "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

For some reason when I right click on Attendee Id table. it only gives me option to refresh. I cannot get into properties!

Comment: The error message is straightforward `AttendeeId` cannot accept a `null` value. You must provide a value to this column, I suggest check if this columns is the PK and if there are an `indentity` or if the column uses `sequence`

Answer (score 2):

Like Sir jean said, you should check your `AttendeeId` if it has constraint.
You should include identity to make it auto increment.
For example in your create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Attendances(
             AttendeeId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
             [other column fields]. . .,

             CONSTRAINT PK_ATTENDANCES PRIMARY KEY(AttendeeId)
)
```

`IDENTITY` is for auto increment